# teTeX Distribution in Slackware

Tags: xetex, pdftex, linux

I have installed slackware 14. It has an in-built support for TeX. The distributions provided are **teTeX** and **eTeX**. Does it make a difference if I install **TeXLive 2013**? Secondly, I am not able to compile the documents using **XeLaTeX** in **slackware**.I can compile only using PdfLaTeX and eTeX.What should I do?

Comment: teTeX has been dead since May 2006. Install [TeX Live 2013 from TUG](http://tug.org/texlive)

Comment: For the second part of the question, I'm pretty sure that teTeX didn't include XeTeX, so no XeLaTeX will be available. I'd second @egreg's comment: install TeX Live. Perhaps he might make that the answer :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The teTeX project has been dead since May 2006, when Thomas Esser announced he would not maintain it any more. See http://www.tug.org/tetex/ for information about this.

At the time, XeTeX was available only for Mac OS X; indeed it was added to TeX Live only in the 2007 release (see Section 9.1.4 of [the TeX Live manual](http://texdoc.net./texmf/doc/texlive/texlive-en/texlive-en.pdf)), so it's not surprising that what you get from Slackware doesn't have it.

In the last seven years, TeX distributions have grown and there are ***many*** packages that weren't available in 2006; many have been updated and also the binaries have been rebuilt and debugged several times.

So my advice is to install TeX Live 2013 from [TUG](http://tug.org/texlive)

The distribution installs into its own tree, under `/usr/local/texlive`, so it won't interfere with the system. Just make sure your `PATH` variable contains

```
/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/<arch>
```

(where in your case `<arch>` stands for `x86_64-linux`, probably).

I usually advise to make a symbolic link

```
ln -s /usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/<arch> /usr/texbin
```

(or `/usr/local/texbin`, if you prefer) and to add `/usr/texbin` to `PATH`, so when a new release is installed, it's sufficient to recreate the right symbolic link, instead of changing the configuration files that set `PATH`.

Comment: After I do all these things, if TeXLive 2014 is introduced will it be necessary to run the command perl install.tk or something else needs to be done?

Comment: @subhamsoni TeX Live has never had a real "upgrade" procedure. Just install the new one, which will use a subtree starting at `/usr/local/texlive/2014`. When you're sure it works well, you can remove `/usr/local/texlive/2013`

Answer (score 1):

Since Slackware still uses teTeX, let me supplement egreg's answer to note that TeX Live packages are available through SlackBuilds.org, an "officially endorsed" Slackware package repository.  Working with these packages should automate both the installation and upgrade procedures.